# How do I forward IPv6 to IPv4?

Tags: ipv6, ipv4

I am testing a LAN network that will be based on IPv6, but without IPv4 support, i cannot connect to other networks.

Can I confirure a router to forward IPv6 requests from local network (LAN) to IPv4 network (WAN side). Also i would like to forward DNS requests the same way.

Router is will be using **Pfsense** or simmilar software.

Comment: i would make an IPv4 tunnel

Answer (score 5):

The protocol combination you want to use for that is DNS64/NAT64. The combination of NAT and DNS will make the whole internet look like IPv6 from your local IPv6 LAN.

There are also some public services that let you try this out. I know of some in Slovenia run by Go6 / Jan Žorž (http://www.internetsociety.org/deploy360/blog/2013/03/open-public-test-of-nat64dns64-at-go6lab/ and http://go6lab.si/current-ipv6-tests/nat64dns64-public-test/) and if you Google you can find others.